# Router with DDNS, unable to update ip in noip

Tags: configuration, dns, ip, router

I have a D-Link DWR-512 router, which i need to create a dynamic dns, so i can access to the router throught the dns instead of the ip.

The router is only connected to solar inverter panels, so i can't use the noIp dynamic update client software to update the IP.

In my router I configured:

[image]

And in My noip account i had:

[image]

It works perfectly. I can acess the router through cipade.smartwatt.net, but when the router reboots then it no longer works. Shouldn't the router update the ip in the noip account?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid error,
Had a white space in the username.